# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: visualforce, javascript, slds

I am creating a VF page using Salesforce Lightning Design. When i am implementing Datepicker i get this error on console every time click on the input box

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>       at main.js:18
>       at new DatePicker (main.js:648)
>       at Function.DatePicker.getDatePicker (main.js:661)
>       at Function.DatePicker.pickDate (main.js:662)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onfocus (captureDate?id=00628000004bbJpAAI&vfRetURLInSFX=%2F00628000004bbJpAAI&isdtp=p1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=htt…:74)
>       at setFocus (main.js:48)
>       at setFocusOnLoad (main.js:46)
>       at bodyOnLoad (captureDate?id=00628000004bbJpAAI&vfRetURLInSFX=%2F00628000004bbJpAAI&isdtp=p1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=htt…:115)
>       at window.bodyOnLoad (main.js:1320)
>       at onload (captureDate?id=00628000004bbJpAAI&vfRetURLInSFX=%2F00628000004bbJpAAI&isdtp=p1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=htt…:12)

For some reason the icon also doesnt appear.

Here is the code

```
<apex:form styleClass="cassa slds-form--stacked" id="forms">
          <div class="cassa slds-form-element">
            <label class="cassa slds-form-element__label" for="myPicker">Select Date</label>
            <div class="cassa slds-form-element__control cassa slds-input-has-icon cassa slds-input-has-icon--right">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="cassa slds-input__icon cassa slds-icon-text-default">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS, 'icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#event')}"></use>
                </svg>
               <!-- <input id="date" class="cassa slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Pick a Date" label="Select Date"/> -->
                <apex:inputField value="{!opp.closeDate}" styleClass="cassa slds-input dates" id="myPicker"/>
            </div>
        </div>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page\\:forms\\:myPicker').datepicker(
        {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        });
});
```

Comment: I've never seen that syntax before. If you just paste `$('#page\\:forms\\:myPicker')` in the dev console, does it return that `input`?

Comment: I think you can simply use `$(document).ready(function() { $('#forms #myPicker').datepicker( { format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }); });`

Comment: @caleb.breckon i had to escape : because jquery was taking it to something related to jquery. i dont remember the exact error